# Google Play Console Account Owner do not have owner permissions

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I am using my Google Play developer account and I have some published apps.

I was in doubt about the owner of the account (I'm the owner, but I was in doubt if I have created another email to be the owner or not).

Here is an image of Google Play Console saying me to contact the account owner, alan******@gmail.com who is the same account that is logged in.

[image]

I've tried to reach Google support but they don't answer me.
I'm not that experienced user, so it can be something newbie.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score -1):

That possibly should be a better message. But it gives the right instructions. You can see [the full help article here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7161426). It says:

> Create a payments profile in payments center to manage and track your app sales from Play Console. Review the list of Supported locations for developer and merchant registration.
>
> - Sign in to Play Console.
> - Click Settings , then click Account details.
> - Under Merchant Account, click Set up a merchant account. You'll be redirected from Play Console to the payments center to set up your payments profile. Make sure to have your business information available to set up your payments profile.

and the help article walks you through the rest of the process.

Comment: But why do we need to set up Merchant Account if we don't have any paid versioned apps?